# Xcode error importing module not being imported

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I left Xcode unsupervised for the weekend and I come back and it's telling me I have missing modules `Corelocation` and `SQLite` at:

```
import SQLite
import CoreLocation
```

both giving me the error `Missing required module 'CSQLite'`. I'm not sure where its getting "CSQLite" especially in relation to `Corelocation`

I have the `SQLite.xcodeproj` added to the general page to be linked it was building fine a couple days ago and absolutely nothing's changed.

Comment: Did you already try closing Xcode and opening it again?  and rebuilding?

Answer (score 1):

In swift, if you want to use sqlite, you can either use modulemap feature of llvm to import c library or you can use cocoapods and import sqlite based any third party pod.

Comment: I'm using this library for my sqlite interface: `https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift`.

Comment: which thirdparty corelocation library you are using. And confirm, if you are using `use_frameworks!`